# How to use the grammar 을/ㄹ 게 아니라?

Tags: grammar, spoken-korean

It looks like the future form of 는 게 아니라, I just want to know how different are its nuances compared to 는 게  아니라. It's difficult to find examples, so that's something that has kept me from fully understanding this grammar.
Thank you.

Comment: Is this the usage you are asking about? https://www.howtostudykorean.com/upper-intermediate-korean-grammar/unit-4-lessons-84-91/lesson-86/ . Please add more details if possible. Sample sentences from the book you are following, for example

Comment: @user17915 yes, that usage, but they don't explain the future tense in that page. I found the future form is explained here: http://ohmykorean.com/?p=1859 but I don't think is enough information. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned the future tense, but, in a normally ordered sentence, the form of the last verb or adjective governs the tense because there are relative and absolute tenses in the Korean language. Please refer to [this](https://www.quora.com/How-many-tenses-does-Korean-have-If-so-what-are-they) to grasp the meaning of relative tense with some pictures.

In general, ...는 게 아니라 (relative present) and ...을 게 아니라 (relative future) are used to **contrast two things** (I would say that 아니라 does not indicate any tense here):

- 옷은 보는 게 아니라 입는 것이다. (Clothes are not things you see but things you wear.)
- 검은 옷만 입는 게 아니라 파란 옷도 입는다. (1. I do not always wear dark clothes; I wear blue/green clothes, too. / 2. I am going to wear not only dark clothes but also blue/green clothes.)
- 지금 입을 게 아니라 겨울에 입을 옷을 샀다. (I (have) bought clothes to wear them not in this season but in winter.)

The first example sentence can be an answer to the question: "How do you define clothes?" Because it ends with 것이다, it is the **absolute present**. You should note that the second one relates to either **absolute present** tense or **absolute (near) future** tense, which is normal for the Korean language. For the third example, *wearing* follows *buying* (You buy clothes and then wear them), so you can see that ...을 게 아니라 here indicates the **relative future** whereas 샀다 indicates the **absolute past**.

The clause including ...는 게 아니라 and ...을 게 아니라 can also be **a reason** for the action said in the following clause, because you can use 아니라 instead of 아니라서:

- 검은 옷만 입는 게 아니라 파란 옷도 샀다. (I do not always wear dark clothes, so I (have) bought blue/green clothes, too.) = 검은 옷만 입는 게 아니라서 파란 옷도 샀다.
- 검은 옷만 입을 게 아니라 파란 옷도 샀다. (I (have) bought blue/green clothes, too, because I was(/am) not going to wear dark clothes only.) = 검은 옷만 입을 게 아니라서 파란 옷도 샀다.
- 앉아만 있을 게 아니라 나가서 뭐라도 한다. (1. I am going out to do something because I am not going to be sitting still only. 2. I am doing something outside (at the moment) because I do not want to be sitting still only.) = 앉아만 있을 게 아니라서 나가서 뭐라도 한다.

As you see, the reason mentioned with ...을 게 아니라 (...을 게 아니라서) relates to the **relative future**.

...을 게 아니라 is, ***however***, quite commonly used to **suggest or order the listerner to do something else**:

- 검은 옷만 입을 게 아니라 파란 옷도 입어라. (Do not always wear dark clothes; wear blue/green clothes, too.)
- 이렇게 앉아만 있을 게 아니라 나가서 뭐라도 해라. (Go out and do something, not just sitting still like this.)

검은 옷만 입을 게 아니라 shows that the speaker thinks the listener is always wearing dark clothes or that the speaker has just seen the listener wearing only dark clothes.

이렇게 앉아만 있을 게 아니라 shows that the listener is sitting still (without doing anything about something) at the moment.

These two examples suggest that ...을 게 아니라 alone relates to the **present** (The listener did, has done, or has been doing something, so she/he will do the same thing unless she/he change her/his minds).

Indeed, ...는 게 아니라 and ...을 게 아니라 are too ambiguous for language learners to use. Fortunately, *we can avoid* using these constructions. These clearer sentences may be used instead of the sentences I wrote above:

- 옷은 보는 물건이 아니고 입는 물건이다.
- 검은 옷만 입지는 않고 파란 옷도 입는다.
- 겨울에 입을 옷을 미리 샀다.
- 검은 옷만 입지는 않으니까 파란 옷도 샀다.
- 검은 옷만 입지는 않을 생각이어서 파란 옷도 샀다.
- 앉아만 있고 싶지 않아서 나가서 뭐라도 한다.
- 검은 옷만 입지는 말고 파란 옷도 입어라.
- 이렇게 앉아만 있지 말고 나가서 뭐라도 해라.

---

If I missed something or if this answer is far beyond your understanding, please leave a comment.